# Using discord.js to check the thumbnail of an embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

I'm new to discord bot developing and I'm trying to understand how to access information from a sent embed. I've been error testing with a bot (full administrator permissions / all toggled privileges) but have been unable to properly detect when an embed has been sent from another bot.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ],
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    // Check if the message contains at least one embed!!
    if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Message contains embed`);
      for (const embed of message.embeds) {
        if (embed.thumbnail && embed.thumbnail.url) {
          console.log(`Thumbnail URL in the embed`);
        }
      }
    } else {
      // If there are no embeds, log the message content
      console.log(`Message content had no embed`);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

I was doing some testing but even when I was 100% certain an embed was sent, "Message content had no embed" was sent to the console. Am I approaching this incorrectly? The bot 100% has administrator permissions so I'm not worried about it not having the correct permissions / privileges

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct for looking at the content of a message. You're just a dunce and forgot to include

```
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
```

silly me....